# highcharts: attempting to create dual-pane chart with data imported from csv

Tags: javascript, csv, highcharts

Here's my problem. I can successfully import data from a CSV, parse it, and load it into one chart. What I *can't* do is create a dual-paned chart using two separate sets of data, both contained in their own variable. Here's a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Jz9z/2/) of the complete code so far.

I parse my data like this:

```
//parsing the csv into series
function createseries(csv, csv2){
    var lines = csv.split('\n'), //separates the lines
    series = [];
$.each(lines, function(i, line){
    item=line.split(',');
    if ( typeof series[item[0]] !== 'object') {
        series[item[0]] = series[series.length] = {
            type: 'scatter',
            name: item[0], //places name, either male or female, as category
            data: [],
        }
    }
    series[item[0]].data.push({
        y: parseInt(item[1]), //places int in y value
        x: parseDate(item[2]), //calls the date function, formats it, places it in x
    });
});

var lines2 = csv2.split('\n'), //separates the lines
    series2 = [];
$.each(lines2, function(i, line){
    item=line.split(',');
    if ( typeof series2[item[0]] !== 'object') {
        series2[item[0]] = series2[series2.length] = {
            name: item[0], //places name, either male or female, as category
            data: [],
        }
    }
    series2[item[0]].data.push({
        y: parseInt(item[1]), //places int in y value
        x: parseDate(item[2]), //calls the date function, formats it, places it in x
    });
});
```

This leaves me with two variables, series, and series 1. If I build the chart using the following code, I get the first series variable plotted.

```
  }],     
     series: series
    });
  }

  createseries(data, data2);
```

But I'm not sure how to get series2 to be plotted on a different pane. Any suggestions? I have a feeling it might be something simple, but I just can't figure it out.